# Ruby on rails: hidden_field_tag convert array into string in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a view for filtering and sorting `activities` table on the `index` action. Parameter for fields to sort set to array and passed throu request to request by `params[:sort]` (`== ["created_at"]`,  for example).

That's works and my params after successful request is:

```
{"direction"=>"desc","sort"=>["created_at"], "controller... etc }
```

Then I added dropbox for filtering table and hidden_field_tag to pass sortable params like that:

```
=form_tag actitvites_path, method: "get"
=radio_button_tag...
=radio_button_tag...
=select_tag...
=hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction]
=hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort]
=submit_tag "Filter", name: nil
```

But `hidden_field_tag` for sorting convert initial value `params[:sort]` == `["created_at"]` to simple `"created_at"` and I don't have any idea why. That is a question. What I get in html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="direction" id="direction" value="asc">
<input type="hidden" name="sort" id="sort" value="created_at">
```

Comment: take `name="sort[]"` and check, `<input type="hidden" name="sort" id="sort" value="created_at">`

Comment: Thanks! It works.But could you explain what's happening there?...because I take a look into docs on hidden_field_tag method and find nothing what is converting args.

Comment: if you want to take array of values into an input, you should say to html that it accepts array values, so `name="sort[]"` tells the Dom that it should take array values.

Comment: added as an answer, please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have `{"direction"=>"desc","sort"=>["created_at"], "controller... etc }`, here, **`sort has an array as value`**

If you want to take `array values` into an `input`, you should say to html that it accepts array values, so `name="sort[]"` tells the Dom that it should take array values

Change,

`<input type="hidden" name="sort" id="sort" value="created_at">`

to,

**`<input type="hidden" name="sort[]" id="sort" value="created_at">`**

Comment: So all this magic defined somethere in html specification, not in the Rails, isn't it?